# Selenium - Edge Browser instance getting closed

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I am trying to execute a sample test case for Edge browser, have downloaded the latest microsoft webdriver for Edge.
While trying to execute the case an Edge instance is opened and getting closed immediately.
Below is my piece of code and the error am facing.

```
static String driverPath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Web Driver";
public static WebDriver driver;

public static void launchBrowser() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver",  driverPath+"\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
    driver = new EdgeDriver();
}
public static void openEdgeBrowser() {
    driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launchBrowser();
    openEdgeBrowser();
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unknown error (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 8.82 seconds
>   Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd10cf2c0560f637404c2d96164b67d9d67', time: '2015-10-09 13:08:06'
>   System info: host: 'LAB-W106411', ip: '10.196.118.201', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:647)
>   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:247)
>   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:129)at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
>   at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.(EdgeDriver.java:152)
>   at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.(EdgeDriver.java:141)at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.(EdgeDriver.java:98)
>   at testscripts.MobileTestingScenario.ExampleThree.launchBrowser(ExampleThree.java:15)
>   at testscripts.MobileTestingScenario.ExampleThree.main(ExampleThree.java:29)

Comment: I've not really got any advice on this one, this thread may be of some help though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34290957/selenium-webdriver-launching-edge-browser ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium webdriver launching edge browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34290957/selenium-webdriver-launching-edge-browser)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like if the version of your *MicrosoftWebDriver.exe* wouldn't match the version of Windows 10 and Edge respectively.

Note that the driver executable that you download from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/ has to match the exact Windos version you are using. (You can use *winver* to find that out.)